# What do these Makefile constructs mean?

Tags: gcc, makefile

Can someone help me figure out the following make file?

```
BINS=file1 file2 file3

all: $(BINS)

clean: 
        rm -f $(BINS) *~ 

$*: $@.c
        gcc -g -o $@ $?
```

Here are my questions:

1. What is the -g option of gcc?
2. What are $* and $@
3. How does it know to execute the last target?

Thanks!

Comment: You should give this question a better name.

Comment: It this the whole makefile? $* as a target is quite strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `gcc` and `make` documentation:

1. "-g   Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format".
2. a. "$*   The stem with which an implicit rule matches (see How Patterns Match). If the target is dir/a.foo.b and the target pattern is a.%.b then the stem is dir/foo. The stem is useful for constructing names of related files. In a static pattern rule, the stem is part of the file name that matched the '%' in the target pattern."

   b. "$@  The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an archive member, then '$@' is the name of the archive file. In a pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern Rules), '$@' is the name of whichever target caused the rule's commands to be run."

   c. "$?  The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target, with spaces between them."  (Not asked, but worth adding.)
3. "'all' Compile the entire program. This should be the default target."

This example makefile is a bit limited, since it seems to only build C programs.  The [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) has several more extensive examples that are useful for learning how to write makefiles.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.) What is the -g option of gcc?

Generate debugging info

> 2.) What are $* and $@

`$*` is the stem of the rule. When you make rule like

```
%.ext: %.otherext
    ext2otherext --input $? --output $@ --logfile $*.log
```

, and the rule tries to make `file.ext` from `file.otherext`, then to log goes to `file.log`

`$@` is the target filename (`file.ext` in the case above).

> 3.) How does it know to execute the last target?

This is a mystery.

`$*` is used for intermediary files: like, when you try to make an `%.so` out of `%.c`, you'll need an intermediary `%.o` which is neither target nor a source. You put:

```
%.so: %.c
    gcc -fPIC -g -c -o $*.o $?
    ld -shared -o $@ $*.o
```

In other words, in a `%.extension` rule, `$*` is everything but the `.extension`.

As a target, `$*` makes no sense.

Are you sure this rule is actually executed somewhere? When I try to reproduce it using your Makefile, it applies default rules (`cc -o`) instead of `gcc -g -o`

Rule you need seems to be:

```
%: %.c
    gcc -g -o $@ $?
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if the makefile works, but I'm too lazy to actually try it.  Did you?

Comment: Yes, I did, it doesn't work :) It makes actually, but uses default rules instead of gcc -g.

Answer (score 1):

[The GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

[GCC online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

Comment: RTFM is not really a helpful answer.

Comment: Technical documentation like this can be pretty opaque. Learning the basics of make through the documentation is about the hardest way I can think of.

Comment: The benefit Chris would gain from reading the manuals to learn the answer to his few basic questions far outweighs any reason for duplicating the content from those manuals here in SO

Comment: This is why I hate coming to this site...It's hard to Google for special characters like $* or $@. And I don't have a lot of time to spend reading a manual.

Comment: @chrisdirulli but i gave you the resources and once on those pages, it's easy to search for those characters.

Answer (score 1):

The first line does just what you'd expect by looking at it — it creates a list of names and assigns it to `BIN`.  Next, a make target called `all` is defined, which is dependent on the targets listed in `$BIN` (`all` can't be built until each target in `$BIN` is built).  `all` is a special build target; if you just run `make` rather than, say, `make clean`, the `all` target is automatically built.  There are no actual commands associated with `all` — it simply ensures that all its dependencies are built.  The last fairly straightforward command defines a build target called `clean`, which deletes each file listed in `$BIN` (note that `$BIN` is being used both as a list of build targets and a list of files in this makefile) and all backups.

Next, we get to a line which is, basically, magic.  `$*` is a special build target which means "anything not specifically defined".  When `make` tries to build `all`, it finds the target and starts work on its dependencies.  But when it tries to build `file1`, there is no explicit target defined.  Instead, it uses `$*` to build `file1`.  Similarly, `$@` gets replaced with the build target's name, and `$?` with its dependencies (sort of; that one you're better off checking the manual for).  When `make` goes to build `file1`, then, the `$*` rule causes it to behave as if the following rule were defined:

```
file1: file1.c
        gcc -g -o file1 file1.c
```

Finally, the `-g` option simply enables debugging information to be compiled in.

Comment: $* is not a special build target, it's not a target at all.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 and Q2 have been answered extensively already, so a brief explanation for Q3 only:

Make always executes the first target unless you specified a different one. This is also called the default target. Usually the default target is called "all".